# Single Slit Diffraction issue with derivation

Tags: optics, interference, diffraction

When deriving the minima, the classical approach is to say

$$ \frac d 2 \sin(\theta)  = \frac{\lambda}2$$

therefore, $$d \sin(\theta) = \lambda$$ It can then be shown for any integer value of $\lambda$. But why couldn't you say that the 2 point sources that interfere destructively are the full width of the slit apart, so $d\sin(\theta) = \lambda/2$, therefore $d\sin(\theta) = \lambda/2$ for destructive interference, which wouldn't be an integer. Maybe I've misunderstood something.

Comment: What about the sources in between the first and last sources? They are not interfering destructively.

Answer (score 0):

you really are misunderstanding. You should consider the slit as the source of many or n elementary waves, so every elementary wave of the first half has the Difference $\lambda/2$ to one of the second half, while in your picture only two of the n waves have the difference of 1/2 all the rest have less, so the amplitude will be smaller, but never zero

Comment: That makes sense. Then my textbook says that you can split the slit into 4, 6, 8, ... parts and claims all $\theta$ such that $\sin\theta=\frac{\lambda m}{d}$ for positive integer $m$ would be destructively interference. So my question would be why can't you split it into $3$ parts and say $\sin\theta=\frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{lambda}{d}$?

Comment: if $sin= \frac{3}{2} \frac{\lambda}{}$ the first  and third part have difference of $\lambda/2$ and interfere to $0$ the rest gives a small max.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thanks!